# Checked repository is removed without consent

Tags: git, macos, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After a certain period (> months) some of my Jenkins pipelines (on MacOS) have to completely re-check out repositories which I check out like with the following snippet. It's like the repository folders were simply deleted.

```
        stage('Checkout: production') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: 'production']],
                extensions: [
                    [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 60],
                    [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false, timeout: 60],
                    [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'production']
                ],
                userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [credentialsId: 'github_access_token', url: 'https://github.com/veryvalidrepo.git']
                ]])
            }
        }
```

That is only happening for some pipelines. The pipeline still runs and is fine but has to fully re-checkout everything and since the checkouts take a long time it's a very annoying thing to happen.

I checked all settings I know and have found nothing activated that might be related to "cleaning up" anything like that.

Is there an explanation for this? And what should I check so it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Something is probably deleting the workspace.  Wouldn't a full checkout every time be more repeatable though?  No way for anything to linger if you always start from clean folders.

Comment: These piplines use dedicated branches where nothing changes unless it has to. In this example it's about the production branch that wasn't touched in months and literally nothing has changed when I revisited it. In this case having to repull hundreds of GBs is just annoying and pointless. And definitely be a choice, right?

Comment: @vik storing hundreds of GBs in Git sounds like a heavy misuse of Git in the first place. The described issue is only a consequence.

Comment: Apart from that, you're using `shallow: false` checkout option that seems to force your pipeline to clone the whole commit history on each build. - _"have to completely re-check out repositories"_ - do you still have any build history available at that point? - _"I checked all settings I know"_ - could you list these settings in your question?

Comment: We use several submodules that are including artist repositories and therefore summing up to a lot of data. The statement that the issue is a consequence is certainly not true because other pipelines for other environments don't have that issue. Not sure what you mean with 'heavy misuse'. But I think this is deviating from the actual issue.

Comment: Using non-shallow checkouts is negotiable but not related to the issue. And with the settings 'I know' I meant the Jenkins settings of which I don't want to post all of them here...